# How can I prevent a Unity object from spilling over a predetermined movement barrier slightly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm currently trying to make a simple Atari Breakout game on Unity and have run into a problem with the paddle (player) movement. Despite it not being allowed to move past the x position 9.15 on the right and -9.15 on the left, it goes just slightly over the barrier, as is shown in the following
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WnNQ.png). Instead of stopping at 9.15 at the rightmost limit, it reaches an x position of 9.199995, causing visible spillage over the gray wall on the right side. The same is true for the left side. I'll attach the code for the paddle which is likely causing the issue here:

```
public class Paddle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2 speed = new Vector2();
    private int movementMult = 1;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(0, -4);
    }

    void onTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "Vertical")
        {
            movementMult = 0;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float inputX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        Vector2 movement = new Vector2(speed.x * inputX * movementMult, 0);

        movement *= Time.fixedDeltaTime;

        if(transform.position.x >= 9.15 && inputX == 1)
        {
            movement.x = 0;
        }
        else if(transform.position.x <= -9.15 && inputX == -1)
        {
            movement.x = 0;
        }

        transform.Translate(movement);
    }
}
```

The onTriggerEnter2D method uses the tag "Vertical" to represent collisions with the vertical "walls" on either side of the screen, which are positioned at the gray sections on either side. The colliders are placed perfectly by zooming in extremely far, so I don't see how those could be an issue.

I honestly don't understand how these if statements are failing to halt the paddle exactly at its intended point. I don't know what to try to attempt to remedy this. What would be a good method to increase the precision at which I can control this collision?

Comment: Are the colliders doing anything? (test this by placing them at a ridiculous position) It seems that the code in FixedUpdate() overrides the transform and thereby ignores the colliders. Just my guess. The if safeguards only trigger after you are already in the wall, and always allow one frame of movement into the wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` statements are not failing. It happens because you stop the movement when the limit is crossed or at the limit. In practice it is on the `FixedUpdate` after the limit is already crossed because it is extremely unlikely exact limit position to happen on some `FixedUpdate`.

To make the paddle stop exactly at the limit you just need to set its position "back" to the limit inside the `if` statements.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    float inputX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

    Vector2 movement = new Vector2(speed.x * inputX * movementMult, 0);

    movement *= Time.fixedDeltaTime;

    if(transform.position.x >= 9.15 && inputX == 1)
    {
        movement.x = 0;
        var pos = transform.position;
        pos.x = 9.15;
        transform.position = pos;
    }
    else if(transform.position.x <= -9.15 && inputX == -1)
    {
        movement.x = 0;
        var pos = transform.position;
        pos.x = -9.15;
        transform.position = pos;
    }

    transform.Translate(movement);
}
```

Because you know the exact coordinates you can alternatively just do:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    float inputX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    Vector2 movement = new Vector2(speed.x * inputX * movementMult, 0);
    transform.Translate(movement * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    var pos = transform.position;
    pos.x = Mathf.Clamp(pos.x, -9.15f, 9.15f);
    transform.position = pos;
}
```

Comment: The second method worked beautifully! Had no idea there was a math clamp function, guess you learn something new every day.

First one though created a very visible glitching effect---guess if statements aren't the way to go with this kind of thing.

Comment: @JustAnotherMusician7 The first method could be modified for `if` statements instead of checking for current `transfrom.position` to check for the next position using `transform.position + movement`. This way the movement will be stopped preemptively avoiding jiggling. All these things depend if you are using `Update` or `FixedUpdate`, move using `transform` or `rigidbody`, all the combinations have their quirks.